# Meaning of Conserved current and charge in QFT

Tags: conservation-laws, symmetry, field-theory

I'm studying QFT and learnead about Noether's Theorem and stuff, made some calculations and, after some help I've got from here, I've managed to learn how to calculate conserved charges and currents associated with a given Lagrangian. But I still don't understand well what these charges and currents mean.